# React: "toISOString is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am coding a Todo List with Next.js. I want to implement a dueDate function, if I make the post request, I get this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: dueDate.toISOString is not a function
```

I dont know how I can fix this, it would be nice if anyone can help me :)

My code:

```
const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState<any>({
    title: "",
    description: "",
})
const [dueDate, setDueDate] = useState<Date>(new Date())
const addTodo = () => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/todos", {
        title: newTodo.title,
        description: newTodo.description,
        dueDate: dueDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10)
    }).then(res => {
        setTodos([...todos, res.data])
        setNewTodo({
            title: "",
            description: "",
            dueDate: "",
        })
    })
}

    
<input className="dueDate" type="date" onChange={(e) => setDueDate(e.target.value)} />
```

Comment: If you edit the `dueDate` value somewhere in the code it could come from here. Otherwise, you might get this error the second time you run the addToto function because after posting the request, the `dueDate` value is set to an empty string and `"".toISOString()` throws a is not a function error.

Comment: Could you provide the entire component code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `input` calls `setDueDate` passing `e.target.value` that is a `string` and not a `Date`, and you know that:

> The "toISOString is not a function" error occurs when the toISOString() method is called on a value that is not a date object.

To solve this it's just necessary to modify input's `onChange`:

```
<input className="dueDate" type="date" onChange={(e) => setDueDate(new Date(e.target.value))} />
```

[For more info](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-typeerror-toisostring-is-not-a-function#:%7E:text=The%20%22toISOString%20is%20not%20a,method%20on%20valid%20date%20objects.)